# Changing progressbar color causes progressbar to not display

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

After searching the site I've found the below code to change the color of my progressbar. This works fine the first time I call the code (progressbar changes to green), however each time after I call the code I get a blank progressbar. Has anyone faced this issue before? If so, what was the solution to be able to change the progressbar color each time 'setProgressDrawable' is called?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

         <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="5dip" />
     <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
            android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#ff747674"
            android:angle="270"
    />
</shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
<clip>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</clip>
</item>
<item
android:id="@android:id/progress">
<clip>
    <shape>
        <corners
            android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/greenStart"
                android:centerColor="@color/greenMid"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="@color/greenEnd"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

**Define colors in strings.xml file**

```
<color name="greenStart">#ff33dd44</color>
<color name="greenMid">#ff0A8815</color>
<color name="greenEnd">#ff1da130</color>
```

**Code to change color**

```
 Rect bounds = bar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
 bar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_progress));
 bar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution to my problem. The progressbar would become blank if the color I was changing to was the same color that was already set. So with my code above the first time the progressbar would change from the default yellow to green. However, the next time the code was called the progressbar (which was already set to green) was agin set to green and as a result the entire progressbar would become blank.

To get around this I've recorded the currently displayed color of the progressbar and when I get around to setting the color again I only set it if it is different then the one currently displayed.

Hope this helps others who find themselves in the same situation.